# Different URL syntax for multilingual SEO with 2 languages

Tags: seo, url, language, geotargeting, cctld

Is there any difference between the syntax here;

```
example.dk/ (danish)
example.dk/en
```

and

```
example.dk/da (danish)
example.dk/en
```

I realise that in the top example, the domain is Danish `.dk`, which makes it implicit that it is Danish, but I would like to know if the second practice influences SEO negatively?

Comment: Relevant question on Stack Overflow (but it isn’t exclusively about SEO): [Should default language of multilingual website be a part of the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38309154/1591669)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how the second version (including a subdirectory of the language in both cases) would have any negative (or positive) SEO impact over the first version (without a subdirectory for the primary language).

The important criteria is that the different language versions have different URLs. Both your URL versions satisfy that criteria.

The subdirectory *name* is just to make the URL unique. For direct-SEO it doesn't even need to be representative of the language - the HREFLANG attributes handle that. Instead of `/da`, you could use `/foo` and I don't think the search engines would really care. However, `/foo` isn't so meaningful for users, so using something that is representative of the language (as you are doing) is obviously better for users (which could indirectly benefit users).

So, I don't think there is any difference between these two URL structures SEO-wise.

> the domain is Danish `.dk`, which makes it implicit that it is Danish

Well, yes, although strictly speaking the domain is Denmark (locale / geo-target).

Answer (score 0):

Your second structure actually has a few advantages, but first a clarification:

Google views most ccTLDs as a "strong signal" that a site is intended for the related country, but it doesn't imply anything about language. So `.dk` indicates Denmark but doesn't say anything about the *language* of a site. Google works out language by looking at the content itself ([ref. here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en)).

So, assuming you want to target people in Denmark, both of your structures are fine from an SEO standpoint. But whenever we have more than one language site on a single domain, it's often better to be consistent and put *each* language inside its own folder. It leaves the domain root free to handle conditional redirects, users can identify the language/locale from the URL, etc.